# Ajax not working with jquery Flip! plugin

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, plugins, flip

I'm trying to use the FLIP! plugin and have it's content loaded by ajax. I'm running into a problem though. It's just not working.

I can see the post event happening in firebug but nothing seems to change when I populate the "content" parameter inside the FLIP! plug in.

Below is my code which may explain things better.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function getFlipContent(url,command, target){   
            $.post(url, {"data": command}, function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                //return response;   // this is not working
                replaceHtml(target,response);  // workaround but kinda not really
            });
        }

        function replaceHtml(object,html){
            $(object).html();
            $(object).html(html);
        }

        $(function(){

            $(".flipable2").bind("click", function() {
                var url= $(this).data("url");
                var command= $(this).data("command");
                var target = $(this).data("target");
                //alert(flip);
                if (target === undefined) {
                    flip = "self";
                }
                if (target == "self") {
                    $($(this)).flip({
                        direction: 'lr',
                        color: '#ffffff',
                        content: function() {
                            getFlipContent(url, command, target);
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    $(target).flip({
                        direction: 'lr',
                        color: '#ffffff',
                        content: function() {
                            getFlipContent(url, command, target);
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                }
            });

        });
</script>


    <body>
    <div id="header">
        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0px" border="0px" cellspacing="0px">
            <tr>
                <td><a href="#" class="flipable2 box" data-target="#page" data-url="test.php" data-command="test">FLIP</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div id="page" class="box">
        BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</td>
    </div>
```

SO right now I'm using a replachtml function to manually re-write the contents of the target I just "flipped". This sorta works but breaks the animation so I really would rather use the plugin's content parameter... When I do that though it just doesn't do anything. The animation completes but there is no content change. I think perhaps I am missing something. Any help would be welcome.

Here is a jsfiddle too: http://jsfiddle.net/mUhuN/9/ though I wasn't sure how to fake an ajax request.

Anyway please help :)

Comment: made a change but still not perfect, tried fetching the ajax first and storing it in a hidden div and then using that div as the content. Works.. but the animations still seems a little clunky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the callbacks to load Ajax before the animation:

```
$("#flipbox").flip({
    direction:'tb',
    onBefore: function(){
            console.log('before starting the animation');
    },
    onAnimation: function(){
            console.log('in the middle of the animation');
    },
    onEnd: function(){
            console.log('when the animation has already ended');
    }
})
```